# Calculating Time difference from multiple value without having any flag in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to calculate break time taken by employee, sample shown here:

```
Userid  Date_time       
------  ---------    
1001    9/1/15 10:31 AM 
1001    9/1/15 11:51 AM 
1001    9/1/15 11:58 AM 
1001    9/1/15 2:02 PM  
1001    9/1/15 2:38 PM  
1001    9/1/15 4:37 PM  
1001    9/1/15 5:12 PM 
1001    9/1/15 6:32 PM 
1001    9/1/15 6:34 PM
1001    9/1/15 7:39 PM  
1001    9/1/15 7:42 PM 
1001    9/1/15 7:53 PM
```

Hence I don't want first and last record because it will be calculated as total working hours.

Expected result:

```
Userid break_time_MIN 
------ -------------- 
1001   83
```

Please suggest how I can calculate the break time for each employee.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Result will be like this    ...  

userid    break_time_MIN
---------   -------------
1001         83         
-
--

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to remove the first and last row. After that, you want to group two consecutive rows and then get their difference. Finally, compute for the `SUM` of all the differences:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = rn - (rn % 2 + 1)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Userid ORDER BY Date_time),
            rnd = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Userid ORDER BY Date_time DESC)
        FROM #tbl
    ) t
    WHERE rn <> 1 AND rnd <> 1
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT
        Userid,
        BreakDuration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Date_time), MAX(Date_time))
    FROM Cte
    GROUP BY
        Userid, grp
)
SELECT
    Userid,
    break_time_MIN = SUM(BreakDuration)
FROM CteFinal
GROUP BY UserId;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485109)</kbd>

```
--------------------- 
Result:
--------------------- 
Userid break_time_MIN 
------ -------------- 
1001   83
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, understood. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Gowthaman Thanks for letting me know. Do not forget to accept any correct answers given here.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  Userid,
        Date_time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY UserId, Date_time) as RN
FROM YourTableName)

SELECT r1.Userid, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,r1.Date_time,r2.Date_time)) as break_time
FROM cte r1
INNER JOIN cte r2 
    ON r1.Userid = r2.Userid AND r1.RN + 1 = r2.RN
WHERE r1.RN % 2 = 0
GROUP BY r1.Userid
```

Output:

```
Userid  break_time
1001    83
```